# Routing error: wrong constant name Clearance/sessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rails-routing, clearance

I've upgraded a rails3 project from clearance 0.8.8 to the latest (0.12.0). followed the wiki instructions to do that.

I'm using an 'admin' prefix to most of the authenticated pages. However, eventhough the routes are all correct, I get a routing error when I try accessing 'session/new'.

I'm overriding the session/new view to apply a specific layout.

Any idea what might be causing of the error?

Here is the output from the logs:

```
Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Oct 05 17:34:05 +0300 2011 
ActionController::RoutingError (wrong constant name Clearance/sessionsController)
```

Comment: Can you share some more code?

Comment: Can you provide the error message? It's hard to mind read :)

Comment: of course, but this is all I am getting in the logs:  

`Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Oct 05 17:34:05 +0300 2011`  

`ActionController::RoutingError (wrong constant name Clearance/sessionsController):`  

browser output error -> https://skitch.com/cnicolaou/f6ci9/clearance-error

Answer (score 1):

The routing error turned out to be a conflicting String#camelize with right_aws gem v2.0.0

All you need to do to get clearance working in this case is update right_aws gem

PS: found the answer here ([devise routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838291/devise-routing-error))